# webview.util.WebViewException: This function must be run from a main thread. in multithreading python

Tags: python, multithreading, webview

I am creating these to thread in my python program but they don't start , it says run then from main thread. i have tried my other codes but not working.
If i don't start thread then my code is working properly but then it freeze my main thread , which i don't want .
I also tried making class and created the run(self) function. but when i call that function using classobj.start() , it does not accept any argument and when i use classobj.run(argument) then my program is running but thread is not starting.

These are my functions which are opening the web views when the thread starts.

```
def openfacebook():
    webview.create_window('Facebook', 'http://www.fb.com')
    webview.start()

def openYoutube():
    webview.create_window('Facebook', 'http://www.youtube.com')
    webview.start()
```

This is my code which i am using to start threads .

```
elif 'open facebook' in query:
    fbThread=Thread(target = openfacebook)
    fbThread.start()
elif 'open youtube' in query:
    ytThread=Thread(target = openYoutube)
    ytThread.start()
```

i want that my main thread keeps on running and these to thread also run on other hand.

```
full exception is :
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "e:\AI Creation\AI\openingWebLinks.py", line 19, in run
    webview.start()
  File "C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\webview\__init__.py", line 74, in start
    raise WebViewException('This function must be run from a main thread.')
webview.util.WebViewException: This function must be run from a main thread.
```

Comment: Please add the name of the package that provides `webview` in your code. A link to its PyPI page would also be helpful. Please also add the full traceback of the exception, so that we can see where it raises. Also, both `elif` branches of your code example execute the same function (`openfacebook`) in a thread assigned to the same name (`fbThread`) and the window created in `openYoutube` is named Facebook. I understand, that this is example code, but please take your time to make it consistent to so that it's easier for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: okay, check now please.

Comment: You still do not specify which package you are using that provides `webview`. I *assume* that it is [`pywebview`](https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/). If that is the case, you simply can't execute `webview.start()` from anywhere else than the main thread of your process. You can create as many windows as you want in advance, `webview.create_window` is non-blocking. The created windows will all show once you start the GUI loop.

Comment: yes i am using pywebview

Comment: if this cant work then what should i try

Comment: It is very much unclear what you are trying to achieve. Creating these windows in separate threads seems pointless. The GUI loop must run in the main thread and will block it. So either you move whatever your main thread is supposed to do after the windows are running to a thread that can run parallel to the main thread or you wrap the activities in a function and pass that function as a parameter to `webview.start()` and have the GUI loop take care of that.

Comment: i am creating these window in thread because if i create them in main thread then my main thread will freeze. but i want  my main thread to keep running

Comment: No, that's what I keep telling you. *Creating windows* does not block; *starting* the loop does.